# What programs do we need to install for Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, sdk

I formatted my computer and have been trying to install Android Studio but have got many errors.
When I tried to install SDKs', I got this error:

```
Downloading http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r22b-windows-x86_64.zip
This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.
```

However, it was downloaded again without any problem.

Then, I got this:

```
Failed packages:
- Layout Inspector image server for API 29-30 (skiaparser;1)
```

I tried to download it again but It didn't work.

After that, I tried to run the default flutter code on Pixel 4 emulator but I got error something like that (I couldn't remember exactly):

```
... "main" error : tag mismatch!
at javax.crpyto....
at javax.crpyto....
at java.security....
```

I fixed this error by deleting JDK 16 and installing JDK 8 (I'm not sure this fixed the errors.) but Android studio is still not working properly.

My question is what are the programs we need to install before installing the android studio? What are the necessary programs for Android studio to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this tutorial to install Android Studio properly:

https://youtu.be/0zx_eFyHRU0